# Get a subclass from a module

Tags: python, inheritance

I would like to get my subclass `Sub` class object from my api.py:

```
import inspect
from tm_base import Base
import tm_child

for k, v in vars(tm_child).iteritems():
if inspect.isclass(v):
    if (Base in inspect.getmro(v) and
                not inspect.isabstract(v)):
        print v
```

When running the api.py I get both:

```
<class 'tm_child.Sub'>
<class 'tm_base.Base'>
```

and I would like `<class 'tm_child.Sub'>` only, this is why I am using `not inspect.isabstract(v)`. I do not see what is wrong with my code..

Here my other files.

tm_base.py

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
```

tm_child.py

```
from tm_base import Base

class Sub(Base):
    pass
```

Comment: Abstract classes have to have abstract methods; the simple presence of the ABCMeta metaclass doesn't make a class abstract. After all, Sub has ABCMeta as its metaclass too, inherited from Base.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it's not considered an abstract class until it has something:

```
class Base:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

print(isabstract(Base)) #=> False

class Base:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def method(self):
        pass

print(isabstract(Base)) #=> True
```

Comment: More about this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410860/determine-if-a-python-class-is-an-abstract-base-class-or-concrete/14410942) SO question

Comment: @Danil Speransky  I added the abstract method decorator to the tm_base, now when I run my code nothing is printed out

Comment: @DanilSperansky  could you edit your code with an example? Thank you for your help