# Python determine if class is abstract (ABC) without abstractmethod

Tags: python, oop, abc, abstract-methods

I have a class that inherits from [`ABC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC), and does not have any `abstractmethod`.

I would like to check if it's an abstract class, and am currently stumped.

[Determine if a Python class is an Abstract Base Class or Concrete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410860/determine-if-a-python-class-is-an-abstract-base-class-or-concrete) prescribes using `inspect.isabstract`.  However, this only works if an `abstractmethod` has been used.

How can I detect if a class inherits directly from `ABC`, without using `inspect.isabstract`?

---

**Test Cases**

```py
# I need this to be flagged as abstract
class AbstractBaseClassNoAbsMethod(ABC):
    pass


# This is currently flaggable with `inspect.isabstract`
class AbstractBaseClassWithAbsMethod(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_method(self):
        """Abstract method."""


# I need this to be flagged as not abstract
class ChildClassFromNoAbsMethod(AbstractBaseClassNoAbsMethod):
    pass
```

I considered using `issubclass(some_class, ABC)`, but this is `True`, even for the above `ChildClassFromNoAbsMethod`.

---

**Current Best Solution**

My current best solution works using `__bases__`.  This is basically just listing parent classes, see [How to get the parents of a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611892/how-to-get-the-parents-of-a-python-class)

```py
def my_isabstract(obj) -> bool:
    """Get if ABC is in the object's __bases__ attribute."""
    try:
        return ABC in obj.__bases__
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

This is a viable solution.  I am not sure if there is a better/more standard way out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AbstractBaseClassNoAbsMethod` **isn't abstract**. Inheriting from `ABC` doesn't make a class abstract. `inspect.isabstract` is producing correct results. You'll also see that no error occurs if you try to instantiate `AbstractBaseClassNoAbsMethod`, while attempting to instantiate an actually abstract class raises an exception.

If you want to test whether a class inherits directly from `abc.ABC`, you can do what you're already doing with `__bases__`, but many abstract classes don't inherit from `abc.ABC`. For example, this is an abstract class:

```
class Abstract(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

and so is `B` in this example:

```
class A(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class B(A): pass
```

but neither `Abstract` nor `B` inherits directly from `abc.ABC`.

Comment: It seems I have a misunderstanding of abstract classes

Comment: Python's implementation of Abstract classes is actually quite peculiar - as the check only takes place in runtime, and when trying to instantiate an abstract class. As far as traditional OOP literature is concerned, Python does not have "abstract classes" at all.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, even if one uses ABCMeta as a metaclass, if there are no abstractmethods (or attributes or properties), a class is *not* abstract for all purposes in Python, since it can be instantiated normally.

That is why `inspect.isabstract` will return False on it.

If you really need this check, then, checking the class `__bases__`  attribute for
`ABC` is the way to go.

And even then, if one just use the metaclass `ABCMeta` directly this check will fail:

```
class MyClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
   pass
```

Now, if we write some code to flag that `MyClass` above as "Abstract" and another one derived from it as "not abstract", as you want with your example `ChildClassFromNoAbsMethod`, then any class derived from ABC would likewise be the "subclass of a class that was declared with ABCMeta metaclass".

Still, it is possible to check if a class has the `ABCMeta` in its metaclass hierarchy, and inspect all the way up its ancestors to "see" if it either is the first class using ABCMeta as a metaclass in its hierarchy, *or* a direct child of `abc.ABC`. But as you've probably noted, it is of little use.

You'd better just have a throw away marker abstract attribute in `yourAbstractBaseClassNoAbsMethod` that would have to be overriden, then both `inspect.iabstract` and the language mechanisms to prevent instantiation would simply work:

```py
In [37]: class A(ABC): 
    ...:     marker = abstractmethod(lambda : None) 
    ...:                                                                                                                             

In [38]: inspect.isabstract(A)                                                                                                       
Out[38]: True

In [39]: class B(A): 
    ...:     marker = None 
    ...:                                                                                                                             

In [40]: B()                                                                                                                         
Out[40]: <__main__.B at 0x7f389bf19cd0>

In [41]: inspect.isabstract(B)                                                                                                       
Out[41]: False
```

Comment: Thank you for adding more color to the answer, and a possible workaround @jsbueno!